# How to calculate students letter grade using class

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

I need to create a program using class that will calculate students' letter grade. For each student, the following data will be read from a file:

- student id - 5 bytes
- student name - 30 bytes
- test1 - 3 bytes
- test2 - 3 bytes
- test3 - 3 bytes

The weighted grade distribution is:

- Test1 30%
- Test2 30%
- Test3 40%

Must print each students info: Names, scores, letter grade, Total of students, and average grade.

I am using pythong 3.7.3

```py
class Student(self):
    dict = {}

    def __init__(self):
    readFile = open('student.txt','r')
    for line in readFile:
        id = line [:5]
        id = id.strip(' ')

        name = line [5:31]
        name = name.strip(' ')

        t1 = line[31:34]
        t1 = int(t1)
        t1 = t1.strip(',')

        t2 = line[34:37]
        t2 = int(t2)
        t2 = t2.strip(',')

        t3 = line[37:40]
        t3 = int(t3)
        t3 = t3.strip(',')

        Student.dict[iden] = id, name, t1, t2, t3
    readFile.close

    def setID(self):
        self.id
    def setName(self):
        self.name
    def setT1(self):
        self.t1
    def setT2(self):
        self.t2
    def setT3(self):
        self.t3
    def getItems(self):
        return Student.dict
    def getID(self):
        return Student.id
    def getName(self):
        return Student.name
    def getT1(self):
        return Student.t1
    def getT2(self):
        return Student.t2
    def getT3(self):
        return Student.t3

def main():
    if (
```

I expect the result output to look like:

```
name                    scores              letter grade
Jason Wells             100,92,80               B
Melanie Parnell         90,64,70                C
Kassie Phan             89,93,97                A

Total number of A's,B',C's
Total number of students
Average grade
```

Comment: please format your code so that indentations make sense. Also your code is missing. Your `main` implementation is broken... Also you might show some code, which is good, but there is no code for solving the actual problem. You must have tried something

Comment: I honestly do not know how to write this code or how to begin tbh.

Comment: Start by fixing the code above...